# continuity and existence of all directional derivatives implies differentiable?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let $f : A \to R$ be continuous

Assume that all directional derivatives exists.

Must $f$ be differentiable?

I think f doesn't have to be differentiable, but i can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct. Consider 
$$
f(x, y) = 
\begin{cases}
    \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2} & \textrm{if}\ (x,y)\neq (0,0)  \\ 
    0 & \textrm{if}\ (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}
$$
It's continuous at $(0, 0)$, since
$$
\left|\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\right|=\left|x\right|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\leq\left|x\right|\to 0
$$
for $(x,y)\to (0,0)$.
Directional derivatives exist everywhere, including $(0,0)$:
$$
D_{(u,v)}f(0,0) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\left(f(0+tu, 0+tv) - f(0, 0)\right)=
\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{t^3u^3}{t\cdot t^2(u^2+v^2)}=\frac{u^3}{u^2+v^2}
$$
But were $f$ differentiable, we'd have
$$
D_{(u,v)}f=\left(D_x\,f\right)\,u + \left(D_y\,f\right)\,v
$$
that is, linear with respect to $u$, $v$. As this is clearly not the case, it follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, even though it's continuous and has directional derivatives.

Comment: thank you

then what additional condition is needed to f be differentiable?

Comment: For example, continuity of partial derivatives.

Comment: Oops, thank you. Seems I've changed my mind in the middle of the formula.

Comment: I tried to edit your answer, but it seems that my edit was not accepted. $u^2+v^2=1$, since $(u,v)$ is a unit vector. So, the result simplifies to $u^3$. It does not affect your conclusion, of course.

Comment: @LGenzelis it is not necessarily a unit vector - it's an arbitrary non-zero vector.

Comment: @MarcinŁoś thanks for that info. I've just run into that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative#Restriction_to_a_unit_vector "some texts restrict the vector v to being a unit vector. With this restriction...". I've never run into a text that doesn't incorporate that restriction, but apparently it is a possibility.