# Differentiability of a scalar function of two variables --- problems with Stewart’s definition.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I’m feeling uncomfortable about how Stewart’s *Calculus* makes the transition from differentiability of functions of one variable to differentiability of functions of two variables. Namely, Stewart gives the following definition:

> **Definition.** A function $ f $ of two variables is said to be differentiable at $ (a,b) $ if the first-order partial derivatives of $ f $ at $ (a,b) $ exist and
>   \begin{align}
>   & ~ f(a + \Delta x,b + \Delta y) - f(a,b) \\
> = & ~ {f_{\operatorname{x}}}(a,b) \Delta x +
>       {f_{\operatorname{y}}}(a,b) \Delta y +
>       {\epsilon_{1}}(\Delta x,\Delta y) \Delta x +
>       {\epsilon_{2}}(\Delta x,\Delta y) \Delta y,
> \end{align}
>   where $ \displaystyle \lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y) \to (0,0)} {\epsilon_{1}}(\Delta x,\Delta y) = \lim_{(\Delta x,\Delta y) \to (0,0)} {\epsilon_{2}}(\Delta x,\Delta y) = 0 $.

**Note.** Later on, he shows that this will follow if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous near $ (a,b) $, and I am fine with this.

What first irked me is that I didn’t remember learning this definition, so I spent a while trying to understand it. Moreover, the only functions that I’ve found to motivate the need for such a definition are those that are *not* continuous at the point in question. For example, consider the function $ f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R} $ defined by
$$
\forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: \qquad
f(x,y) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{x y}{x^{2} + y^{2}} & \text{if $ (x,y) \neq (0,0) $}; \\
0                          & \text{if $ (x,y) = (0,0) $}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $ f_{\operatorname{x}} $ and $ f_{\operatorname{y}} $ are defined at $ (0,0) $, but $ f $ is not continuous there.

Here’s my quarrel. I don’t think that this is a natural extension from the one-dimensional case. In one dimension, differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point, but two dimensions, the existence of $ f_{\operatorname{x}} $ and $ f_{\operatorname{y}} $ at a point don’t imply the continuity of $ f $ at that point. My intuition, then, is that to extend the definition of differentiability to two dimensions, we should say that $ f_{\operatorname{x}} $ and $ f_{\operatorname{y}} $ exist and that $ f $ is continuous at the relevant point.

This seems nice and simple, so I can’t imagine why Stewart would go with the awkward definition given at the beginning of this post, if this was indeed the case. It therefore seems that I should be wrong. If I am, can you give me an example of a function $ f $ that is continuous at $ (a,b) $, and $ f_{\operatorname{x}} $ and $ f_{\operatorname{y}} $ are defined at $ (a,b) $, but it isn’t differentiable there?

Additionally, I have a rough outline of a proof in my head of why it should be true. The definition of a directional derivative gives
$$
  {D_{\mathbf{u}} f}(a,b)
= \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h \Delta x,b + h \Delta y) - f(a,b)}{h},
$$
but expressing it as a gradient implies that
$$
  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a + h \Delta x,b + h \Delta y) - f(a,b)}{h}
= {f_{\operatorname{x}}}(a,b) \Delta x + {f_{\operatorname{y}}}(a,b) \Delta y.
$$
However, for this limit to be true, it seems like the original awkward definition must follow, i.e.,
$$
  \frac{f(a + h \Delta x,b + h \Delta y) - f(a,b)}{h}
= {f_{\operatorname{x}}}(a,b)\Delta x + {f_{\operatorname{y}}}(a,b) \Delta y,
$$
which implies that
$$
  f(a + h \Delta x,b + h \Delta y) - f(a,b)
= {f_{\operatorname{x}}}(a,b)h \Delta x + {f_{\operatorname{y}}}(a,b)h \Delta y
$$
without even the need for the functions $ \epsilon_{1} $ and $ \epsilon_{2} $.

---

**Edit 1**

zhw. has given a nice counter example below. However, I’d now like to alter my questions.

> 1. Would an alternative definition be that all the directional derivatives of $ f $ exist and that $ f $ is continuous at a given point?
> 2. What if I now extend my original approach to say that $ f $ is continuous on a neighborhood of $ (a,b) $ and that $ {f_{\operatorname{x}}}(a,b) $ and $ {f_{\operatorname{y}}}(a,b)$ exist? Could you give me a counterexample now?

---

**Edit 2**

zhw. has knocked down Question 2 of Edit 1 in his response to my comment to his original answer, so now I’m just wondering if

> Would an alternative definition be that all the directional derivatives of $ f $ exist and that $ f $ is continuous at a given point?

I’m motivated to ask because (a) zhw.’s counter examples all have some directional derivatives that don’t work and (b) my attempted proof relied on the existence of directional derivatives.

Comment: Nicely written question.

Comment: Your proposal has an awkwardness of its own. In the one-dimensional case, it doesn’t simply reduce to the usual definition of the derivative. Instead, you’ve got an alternate definition which requires that the function be continuous and that its left and right derivatives at a point (which thus need to be defined first) exist.

Comment: @amd, I don't think that is too awkward because in 1d the existence of a derivative implies equality of it's left and right derivatives and continuity of the function. So I don't think it is a big stretch to need these. But I guess that is besides the point. I thought maybe it could still work because the example you linked to is not continuous, however, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/784222/continuity-and-existence-of-all-directional-derivatives-implies-differentiable      is continuous as well. So my intuition is wrong. :(

Comment: Curses, foiled again! ;) I think the exercise of figuring out that these necessary conditions are insufficient was worthwhile, anyway. What it really comes down to is the same difficulty as for defining limits once you add even one more dimension: you add a *lot* of paths that need to be considered.

Comment: Fundamentally, my objections to adding more conditions to define differentiability are that it feels like putting the cart before the horse and adds extra concepts to the one-d definition that weren’t needed in the standard definition for it (and turn out not to be needed when generalizing that, either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are functions for which *all* directional derivatives exist and are still not differentiable. A web search will turn up several examples such as [this one](http://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Existence_of_directional_derivatives_in_every_direction_not_implies_differentiable), in which not only do they all exist but are equal. It fails to be differentiable because *all* paths need to be considered, not just the straight lines. Requiring continuity as well likely does the trick, but to me that seems like using a bigger and bigger hammer to deal with each issue as it arises.

I think the awkwardness in the text’s definition comes from treating $x$ and $y$ separately. If you formulate the definition of differentiability in terms of vectors, it doesn’t seem all that awkward to me: A function $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $\mathbf v\in\mathbb R^m$ if there exists a linear map $L_{\mathbf v}:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ such that $f(\mathbf v+\mathbf h) = f(\mathbf v)+L_{\mathbf v}(\mathbf h)+o(\mathbf h)$. If such a map exists, it isn’t hard to show that it is unique. This linear map is the differential of $f$ at $\mathbf v$, often denoted by $\mathrm df_{\mathbf v}$ or simply $\mathrm df$. This captures the essential notion that a derivative/differential is the best linear approximation to the the change in function’s value near a given point.

Note that when $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ this definition reduces to that of the derivative from elementary calculus (in one dimension, a linear map is just multiplication by a scalar). In addition, gradient, directional derivative, &c can all be defined in terms of this differential.

Comment: Could you give the example where all the directional derivatives exist and it is still not differentiable? Overall I'm still unhappy with this. In particular, I want to take as given that the function is continuous since that is necessary in the 1d case. But if it's continuous then the function will $f(a+\Delta x, b+\Delta y)-f(a,b)$ will automatically tend toward 0. As you concluded, the idea is that this "derivative" is the best linear approximation. But isn't the tangent plane to zhw.'s example still the "best" linear approximation?

Comment: @Fractal20 See the edited answer for an example. Your approach will certainly work eventually, but imposing more and more conditions on the function isn’t the most parsimonious way to proceed and seems backward to me. All of the conditions you’re adding are already *consequences* of this definition of differentiability, which itself is a fairly straightforward generalization of the one-dimensional definition from elementary calculus. At this point, we’re starting to argue esthetics.

Comment: @Fractal20 Your point about the tangent plane is well-taken, but then, how do you define this object rigorously? With the differential in hand, the tangent hyperspace of a scalar-valued function $f$ ends up being given by the kernel of $\mathrm df$, so it, too, might be considered a *consequence* of this relatively simple definition.

Answer (score 2):

Define $f$ to be $0$ on the axes, and $f(x,y) = \sqrt { x^2+y^2}$ elsewhere. Then $f$ is continuous at $(0,0),$ and $\partial f/\partial x (0,0) = 0 = \partial f/\partial y (0,0).$ Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0).$ Verify that the definition would then yield $f(x,x)=o(x)$ as $x\to 0.$ But $f(x,x) = \sqrt 2 |x|,$ contradiction, showing $f$ is not differentiable at $(0,0).$

Comment: Touche! However, I have some quibbles. Or I'm just confused. In particular, fitting to Stewart's definition $f(\Delta x, \Delta y) - f(0,0) = \sqrt{\Delta x^2 + \Delta y^2}$ which does tend towards 0 (though admittedly it isn't in the form of $\epsilon_1\Delta x$). So is the idea that it must be exactly of that form? Also, your answer makes me wonder if an alternative definition would be that any direction derivative exists? And finally, what if I expand my definition to say that f is continuous in a neighborhood of the point and $f_x$, $f_y$ exist (though not necessarily in the neighborhood?)

Comment: Note that $\epsilon_1\Delta x $ doesn't just tend to $0,$ it is $o(x)!!$ I think $xy/\sqrt {x^2 + y^2}$ will also work, answering your last question.

Comment: Foiled again. Okay, I'd still like to know if it could be equivalent to saying that all the directional derivatives exist. I'm motivated to ask that also because that is what my attempted proof used. Also, that does seem like a nice extension of the 1d concept: that it should be differentiable in any slice through the point in question. As for the tending to 0 I'm still confused because the original definition didn't specify the speed at which it tended towards 0. And did you mean $o(\Delta x)$?

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, so I have decided to make it into a post instead.

---

Throughout this discussion, let us fix the following objects:

- A natural number $ n $.
- A subset $ D $ of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $.
- A point $ \mathbf{a} $ in the interior of $ D $.
- A function $ f: D \to \mathbb{R} $.

---

According to certain textbooks, $ f $ is differentiable at $ \mathbf{a} $ if and only if there exists a $ \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ such that
$$
\forall r \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}: \qquad
\mathbb{B}(\mathbf{a};r) \subseteq D \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
  \lim_{\substack{0 < \| \mathbf{h} \| < r \\ \mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}}
  \frac{|
       f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{a}) - \mathbf{v} \bullet \mathbf{h}
       |}
       {\| \mathbf{h} \|}
= 0.
$$
A simple argument using the standard basis vectors of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ shows that if $ f $ is differentiable at $ \mathbf{a} $, then the first-order partial derivatives of $ f $ at $ \mathbf{a} $ exist, and furthermore, $ \mathbf{v} = {\nabla f}(\mathbf{a}) $. Hence, when $ n = 1 $, we recover the definition of differentiability for single-variable functions.

I shall now proceed to show that the standard definition above is equivalent to Stewart’s.

---

Suppose that $ f $ is differentiable at $ \mathbf{a} $ in the sense of Stewart. Choose any $ r \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} $ with $ \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{a};r) \subseteq D $. Then the following are true:

- The first-order partial derivatives of $ f $ at $ \mathbf{a} $ exist.
- There exists a function
  $ \epsilon: \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ such that
  $$
    \forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r): \qquad
      f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{a})
    = {\nabla f}(\mathbf{a}) \bullet \mathbf{h} +
      \epsilon(\mathbf{h}) \bullet \mathbf{h}
    $$
  and
  $$
    \forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{\leq n}: \qquad
      \lim_{\substack{0 < \| \mathbf{h} \| < r \\ \mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}}
      {\epsilon_{k}}(\mathbf{h})
    = 0.
    $$

By the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, we have
\begin{align}
\forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) \setminus \{ \mathbf{0} \}: \qquad
       \frac{|
            f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{a}) -
            {\nabla f}(\mathbf{a}) \bullet \mathbf{h}
            |}
            {\| \mathbf{h} \|}
& =    \frac{|\epsilon(\mathbf{h}) \bullet \mathbf{h}|}{\| \mathbf{h} \|} \\
& \leq \frac{\| \epsilon(\mathbf{h}) \| \| \mathbf{h} \|}{\| \mathbf{h} \|} \\
& =    \| \epsilon(\mathbf{h}) \|.
\end{align}
It then follows from the Squeeze Theorem that
$$
  \lim_{\substack{0 < \| \mathbf{h} \| < r \\ \mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}}
  \frac{|
       f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{a}) -
       {\nabla f}(\mathbf{a}) \bullet \mathbf{h}
       |}
       {\| \mathbf{h} \|}
= 0.
$$
As $ r $ was chosen arbitrarily, $ f $ is therefore differentiable at $ \mathbf{a} $ by the standard definition.

---

Suppose that $ f $ is differentiable at $ \mathbf{a} $ by the standard definition. As mentioned earlier, the first-order partial derivatives of $ f $ at $ \mathbf{a} $ exist. Picking any $ r \in \mathbb{R}_{> 0} $ with $ \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{a};r) \subseteq D $, we now commit ourselves to finding a function $ \epsilon: \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ that satisfies Stewart’s definition.

Firstly, define $ e: \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) \to \mathbb{R} $ by
$$
\forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r): \qquad
                        e(\mathbf{h})
\stackrel{\text{df}}{=} f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{a}) -
                        {\nabla f}(\mathbf{a}) \bullet \mathbf{h}.
$$

Secondly, define $ \phi: \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) \to \mathbb{R} $ by
$$
\forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r): \qquad
\phi(\mathbf{h}) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\begin{cases}
e(\mathbf{h}) / \| \mathbf{h} \| & \text{if $ \mathbf{h} \neq \mathbf{0} $}; \\
0                                & \text{if $ \mathbf{h} = \mathbf{0} $}.
\end{cases}
$$
By the definition of differentiability, $ \phi $ is continuous on $ \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) $.

Thirdly, define $ C: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} $ by
$$
\forall \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \qquad
C(\mathbf{x}) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\begin{cases}
  \| \mathbf{x} \| / \| \mathbf{x} \|_{1}
& \text{if $ \mathbf{x} \neq \mathbf{0} $}; \\
  0
& \text{if $ \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{0} $}.
\end{cases}
$$
Here, $ \| \cdot \|_{1} $ denotes the [taxicab norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm) on $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $. It is not hard to see that $ 0 \leq C(\mathbf{x}) \leq 1 $ for all $ \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $.

Next, observe that
$$
\forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r): \qquad
  e(\mathbf{h})
= \sum_{k = 1}^{n}
  [\phi(\mathbf{h}) C(\mathbf{h}) \operatorname{sgn}(\mathbf{h}_{k})]
  \mathbf{h}_{k},
$$
where $ \operatorname{sgn} $ denotes the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). We may thus define $ \epsilon: \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r) \to \mathbb{R}^{n} $ by
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{\leq n}, ~
\forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r): \qquad
                        {\epsilon_{k}}(\mathbf{h})
\stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \phi(\mathbf{h}) C(\mathbf{h})
                        \operatorname{sgn}(\mathbf{h}_{k}).
$$
Using the fact that both $ C $ and $ \operatorname{sgn} $ are bounded pointwise in absolute value by $ 1 $, we obtain
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{\leq n}, ~
\forall \mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{B}(\mathbf{0};r): \qquad
|{\epsilon_{k}}(\mathbf{h})| \leq |\phi(\mathbf{h})|.
$$
It then follows from the continuity of $ \phi $ and the Squeeze Theorem that
$$
\forall k \in \mathbb{N}_{\leq n}: \qquad
  \lim_{\substack{0 < \| \mathbf{h} \| < r \\ \mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}}
  {\epsilon_{k}}(\mathbf{h})
= 0.
$$
As $ r $ was chosen arbitrarily, $ f $ is therefore differentiable at $ \mathbf{a} $ by Stewart’s definition.

---

> **Conclusion:** The two definitions of differentiability are equivalent.